# CustomTkinter(python) I cannot put a label inside of a frame that is inside a TopLevel window

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Using Custom Tkinter python I have put a label inside of a frame that is inside of a TopLevel Window. The frame can be inside of said window but when I try the label inside of the frame, the label appears on the main window.

```
def OpenMessageScreen(client):
    #exec(client + " = tk.CTkToplevel(window) ")
    evrenacar = tk.CTkToplevel(window)
    #exec(client + "Frame123 = tk.CTkFrame(master =" +client +",width=300).pack()")
    evrenacarFrame123 = tk.CTkFrame(master = evrenacar,width=300).pack()
    exec(client + "Label = tk.CTkLabel(master=" + client + "Frame123,text = \'test\').pack()")
    evrenacarLabel = tk.CTkLabel(master=evrenacar.frame("evrenacarFrame123"),text="merhana")
    evrenacarLabel.pack()  


MessageTestButton = tk.CTkButton(master=MessageFrame,command=lambda: OpenMessageScreen("evrenacar")).pack()
```

`MessageFrame` is just a frame on the Main Window, and `evrenacar` is the client name (just a variable name not important).

And if you are wondering about the commentary sections and replaced variable versions with the same code on the function. That's just a test to make sure `exec()` is not the cause of this problem. (it is not)

I have created a `Toplevel` window that activates using a button. When the button is pressed, it has a command that names the top level window as the `lamba` function below, that using that variable client, it can produce more then one windows(the exec function that creates more then one window isn't the problem). The window works fine, and I have put a frame inside of it. But when I try putting a label inside of said frame, the label appears on the main window. Can you help me solve this bug.

[image: Output (Image)]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
evrenacarFrame123 = tk.CTkFrame(master = evrenacar,width=300).pack()
```

If you examine `evrenacarFrame123` you would see that it's `None`. When you use `None` (or a variable set to `None`) as the master of a widget, that widget will appear in the root window.

Why is `evrenacarFrame123` set to `None`? In python, `foo = x().y()` always sets `foo` to the return value of `.y()`. In tkinter, `pack()` always returns `None`, so `SomeWidget(...).pack()` will always return `None`.

The solution is to separate the creation of the widget from the layout.

```
evrenacarFrame123 = tk.CTkFrame(master = evrenacar,width=300)
evrenacarFrame123.pack()
```

If you want to prevent creating a widget in the root window in case of specification of `None` as a master of the widget, you can call the function `NoDefaultRoot()` in the `tkinter` module to turn this default behavior off.

After calling `NoDefaultRoot()` you will get the error message `RuntimeError: No master specified and tkinter is configured to not support default root` if you have passed `None` as a master widget when creating a new widget.

Comment: Surprising behavior ... I would expect an error or at least a warning. Assuming it would be an error if trying to place a widget in `None` makes it really hard to directly see the reason for the problem, even if it is obvious that it is not done the right way.

Comment: @Claudio: you can call the function `NoDefaultRoot()` in the tkinter module to turn this behavior off. If you call that function, then passing `None` as the master of a widget will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness to give an example how `NoDefaultRoot()` works while using default tkinter module (see the answer by *Bryan Oakley*) run the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

# ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== 
root       = tk.Tk()
toplevelWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
tk.Label(master=toplevelWindow, text="toplevelWindow:  Label-Toplevel").pack()
tk.Label(master=None,           text="master=None: Label-Root").pack()
root.mainloop()


# ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== ===== 
tk.NoDefaultRoot()
root       = tk.Tk()
toplevelWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
tk.Label(master=toplevelWindow, text="toplevelWindow:  Label-Toplevel").pack()
tk.Label(master=None,           text="master=None: Label-Root").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

to experience both, creation of a widget in the root window and the error message raised while using  `tk.NoDefaultRoot()`.